# Supply second optional argument without need to suply first optional argument?

Tags: c++, parameter-passing, optional-parameters

I have a function like this:

```
 void foo(int optionalinteger=0, float optionalfloat=0.0f, cell *optionalarray=NULL)
 {
          return;
 }
```

I tried to acces an optional argument like

```
 foo(.optionalfloat=5.5f); // from another programming language
```

but that gives an error.
How do I access only the optional value I choose to without the need to supply other optional values?

Comment: IIRC, you'll need to make several overloads to do this.

Comment: can you give an example?

Comment: Two versions of the same function, with and without the first operand. To avoid code duplication, you can have a "master" version and have all the overloads call that master.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you really want to, you can use something akin to the [named parameter idiom](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/named-parameter-idiom.html), e.g.:

```
struct cell;

void foo(int optionalinteger, float optionalfloat, cell *optionalarray) {}

struct foo_params {
  foo_params& integer(int v) { integer_ = v; return *this; }
  foo_params& fl(float v) { fl_ = v; return *this; }
  foo_params& array(cell *v) { array_ = v; return *this; }

  // C++11 defaults for laziness, easy to change though
  int integer_=0;
  float fl_=0.0f;
  cell *array_=nullptr;
};

void foo(foo_params params = foo_params()) {
  foo(params.integer_, params.fl_, params.array_);
}

int main() {
  foo(foo_params().integer(100)
                  .array(0));
}
```

That's quite a lot of work for something quite simple and counter-intuitive if you're not really expecting to see something like that in your code base.

Or you could use the [boost named parameter library](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_48_0/libs/parameter/doc/html/index.html) if you prefer.

Answer (score 4):

Depending on your needs, you could overload the `foo()` function.

```
void foo(int optionalinteger=0, float optionalfloat=0.0f, cell *optionalarray=NULL)
{
    return;
}

void foo( float optionalfloat )
{
    foo( 0, optionalfloat, NULL );
}
```

This solution is of course limited as it will not work in all situations. If given the following method

```
void foo(int optlint=0, float optflt1=0.0f, float optflt2=0.0f, cell *optionalarray=NULL)
{
    return;
}
```

It would not be possible to create individual overloaded functions for both `float` parameters.

Comment: You should probably do: `void foo( float optionalfloat, cell *optionalarray=NULL)`

Comment: The question asked for a way to provide only one optional argument without the need to provide others. It would prove useful though.

Answer (score 2):

Personally I would add two overloads:

```
void foo(int optionalinteger=0, float optionalfloat=0.0f, cell *optionalarray=NULL);

// Note: afloat not optional
void foo(float afloat , cell *optionalarray=NULL) {foo(0, afloat, optionalarray);}

// Note: anarray not optional
void foo(cell *anarray)                           {foo(0, 0.0f, anarray);}
```

That way you can call with any set of parameters.